# How to upload audio file from Vue.js to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I tried uploading an audio file like an image, but it didn't work. How do I extract data from an audio file and send it to Laravel?

```
<input
type="file"
class="user-edit-form browse-file"
accept=".mp3,audio/*"
@change="uploadSong"
>

uploadSong (e) {
      console.log(e)
      this.songUpload = e.target.files[0]
      if (!this.songUpload.length) {
        return
      }
      this.createSong(this.songUpload[0])
    },
createSong (file) {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      let vm = this
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        vm.song = e.target.result
        console.log(e.target.result)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
```

Comment: Did you setup contentType of your ajax request to `multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: Yes, I did that, but still it's not working.

Comment: See my answer. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
<input type="file" id="inputName" name="inputName"  v-on:change="fileData(this)" />
```

On Chnage:

```
fileData(element){
   var filedata = $(element).prop("files")[0];
   var fileName = file_data.name;
   var fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: It says {
 "owner": "eslint",
 "code": "no-undef",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "'$' is not defined.",
 "source": "eslint",
 "startLineNumber": 418,
 "startColumn": 25,
 "endLineNumber": 418,
 "endColumn": 26
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

Input:

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
```

on file change:

```
handleFileUpload(){
    this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
}
```

Finally on form submit:

```
    submitAudioFile(){

            let formData = new FormData();

            // add file

            formData.append('file', this.file);

            axios.post( '/upload',
                formData,
                {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
              }
            )
        .then(function(){
           console.log('success');
        })
        .catch(function(){
           console.log('failed');
        });
```

Comment: I have headers set to headers: { 'Accept': 'Application/json' }. And I also tried the one you suggested. It still is not working. Not sure what the problem is!!!

Comment: I tried this
const formData = new FormData()
          formData.append('song', this.songUpload)
          this.$http.post('/upload',
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              }
            }
          )
            .then(res => {
              console.log(res)
            })

Comment: You can set multiple headers. Try adding Content-Type header.

Comment: It worked, like your code...thanks a lot... @Manzurul